# How to set ACLs so a user can control any dir content, but not the dir itself and not file permissions?

Tags: freebsd, acl, freenas, nfsv4, setfacl

I'm using FreeBSD and ZFS (I think FreeNAS uses NFSv4 ACLs).

I want to grant access to a group of users (group name: `publicfiles_rw_users`) and allow them to modify, create, and delete all files and dirs **within/below** a directory (path: `/mnt/mydata/files/publicfiles/pub`), but not let them delete/rename/move the `/mnt/mydata/user/publicfiles/pub` **directory** itself, and they can't change/modify ACLs on anything (all permissions are inherited without exception).

Of course other groups will also have access, but it's the ACLs I need to manage this group, which I'm unclear about.

As background, almost everything below `/mnt/mydata/user` inherits ACLs from that directory, so I can see that it will need an additional ACL entry added on `pub`. I'm not sure if I can simply allow all other ACLs to continue inheriting as before, or what else I have to do.

What is the cleanest way to do this, with `setfacl`?

Comment: You have contradictory requirements, so the question is unanswerable.  Creating and deleting files _is_ modifying a directory, so one cannot both have the permission for the former and not have it for the latter.

Comment: Surely not in the sense I'm after, otherwise one could never create a directory like `myftp/files/pub` in which users could upload files, without also giving them permission to delete `pub` itself. Perhaps I should be clearer and reword - _"without deleting/moving/renaming the dir"_. Modifying the dir only in regard to last time changed, or files it contains, isn't an issue. Question edited, does that resolve the problem?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that you are after too.  Deleting or renaming the directory `pub` is not the same as deleting or renaming the things in directory `pub`, and they are not both denoted _permission to modify directory `pub`_.  It is after all, the parent of `pub` that is modified in the former cases.

Comment: This feels like miscommunication - probably on my part! Can we move to chat to clarify the mistake, so I can word the question more appropriately? My observation is that if what I want isn't possible, then granting permission to any user to create/delete/modify files in `pub` would necessarily imply permission to delete/move/rename `pub` itself... which would by the same logic necessitate permission to delete/move/rename `publicfiles`.... which would imply by the same logic permission to delete/rename/move `files`.. all the way up to `/`. ......

Comment: As that can't possibly be correct, I must be miswording the question so that what I'm asking isn't what I actually want. But comments aren't an ideal way to explore that. Can we move to chat at least to the point where the question is fixed?